# Inserting a value into HashSet getting a reference to it

Tags: rust, containers

I need to refer to a value after inserting it into set. However after inserting the container becomes the owner of the element and I can no longer refer to it. Is this achievable without updating the containers API?

Ideally I'm looking for some function with the following signature:

```rust
fn insert_referring<A>(set: &mut HashSet<A>, element: A) -> &A
```

Comment: You can wrap your objects into a `Rc`.

Comment: That would work, but would also incur overhead. I hope to find a solution, which wouldn't.

Comment: I'm with you: unfortunately, I think that this would require a new method.

Comment: In your situation, I would use a `HashMap` to retrieve the value easily.

Comment: Can you clear this out as an answer possibly?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b39ea14bea827fb135914776207bc6da)

Comment: You can refer to the value from the `HashSet` using [`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.get). However this requires an additional lookup. I don't think there is a way to do it in a single step.

Comment: You should create an issue to add this.

Comment: A `HashSet<T>` is a `HashMap<T, ()>`; thus the duplicate

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I mean, you could create your own handle as a key to retrieve the value easily, but that's specific to your need.